# Polyfit and pearsonr generating signigicant p values with random data

Tags: random, machine-learning, ipython, correlation, curve-fitting

Running this code in IPython I would expect no significant p value for spearmanr/pearsonr to be generated except on the expected level of chance, but on every 6th or 7th run I get very high significance values like 1e-20.

I am trying to *jackknife* out inferred values based off a various types of polynomial fittings but this example demonstrates the core of the issue I am facing. Since each value in `new_pairs` is calculated with a leave-one-out approach, I'm a total loss for why I get significance on random data like this from polyfit as it has not seen the example, and it was given random data to learn on in the first place.

```
import scipy.stats

x=numpy.random.randn(50)
y=numpy.random.randn(50)
pairs = zip(x,y)
new_pairs = []

for p_i,p in enumerate(pairs):
        train_pair = pairs[:p_i] + pairs[p_i+1:]
        nx,ny = zip(*train_pair)
        tx,ty = pairs[p_i]
        m_l = poly1d(polyfit(nx,ny,1))
        new_pairs.append( (m_l(tx),ty) )

v,w = zip(*new_pairs)
#scatter(v,w,c='green',s=70)
print scipy.stats.spearmanr( v,w )
```